# while sending data to spring mvc i am getting bad request error(submition of form) in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var dataObj = {  
      'email' : $scope.registration.email ,   
      'name' : $scope.registration.name ,   
  'number' : $scope.registration.number ,  
  'ip' : $scope.registration.ip  
 };
$http({   
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/temp/create',  
      data: dataObj ,   
      headers : { 
                 'Accept': 'application/json',  
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'  
                }  
      }).success(function(data) {
      $location.path('/back');  
       alert("Task marked completed");
      });
```

registration is object coming from my html page while transferring this data i am getting 400 error message

Comment: I suggest you read the error message, and the server logs, and the server code. Knowing the *client* code doesn't allow us to know why the *server* doesn't accept the data. Note that your headers are useless. Angular adds them by default.

Comment: Thank you for your replay.. my error was solved due to range of data storage exceds its getting error